# OpenDialogCommand how to include Buttons in dialog_options

Tags: 8, ajax, javascript

How can I inlcude buttons in OpenDialogCommand?

```
$options = [
        'dialogClass' => 'my-dialog-class',
        'width' => '700px',         
        'buttons' => [
          'text' => 'Continue',
          'class' => 'btn-primary ok-button',
          'click'=> "function() { $(this).dialog('close'); }",
  ],
      ];

      $response->addCommand(new OpenModalDialogCommand($title, $content, $options));
```

This seems not to work. The class is set, but no buttons are shown.

Answer (score 0):

In the $options array the element "buttons" must be a "multiple" array.
For example:

```
$options = [
  'dialogClass' => 'my-dialog-class',
  'width' => '700px',
  'buttons' => [
    [
      'text' => 'Continue #1',
      'class' => 'btn-primary ok-button',
      'click' => "function() { $(this).dialog('close'); }",
    ],
    [
      'text' => 'Continue #2',
      'class' => 'btn-primary ok-button',
      'click' => "function() { $(this).dialog('close'); }",
    ],
  ],
```